# Viber icon missing on panel in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, panel

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I've installed Viber and I'm struggling for days with this problem. My Viber icon is located at the top left corner, few milimeters to the right from the dash icon. I have tried to whitelist it on desktop enviroment variables, it wroked with Skype, but not with Viber. Also, I have to mention that I've installed it via .deb package and via terminal, and the problem still persists. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem after install the viber on ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

**Solution:**

**Step1 :** 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/481614/viber-notification-is-not-in-the-right-position?newreg=8c55c17661614722b7db6f58eea38e51

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade`

**Step2:** Log Out and log In
**Step3:** After log In you can see the viber notificaiton  icon in the right but maybe new icon( keyboard) add to the try.
 
For remove this icon please 
 1.Right click on keyboard icon
 2.Select preferences
 3.In general tab remove check the "Show icon on system tray"